# Allocating space in assembly (Insert function)

Tags: memory, assembly, sparc

I'm working on an assembly equivalent to an insert function and I was wondering how exactly i would space the elements of the list so I can fit my data in there. I have found the correct address for where my information should be inserted, but I am a bit confused as to how to write my data without overwriting what is there. My idea is

```
    set givespace, %l1
    !Next part is at the bottom in data section
    .section ".data"
    givespace:
          .align 48
```

where 48 is the size of my element. That is giving me an error invalid alignment boundary. Any ideas?

Comment: as far as i understand `.align 48` will try to align the address of the following to a multiple of 48 (which honestly makes not so much sense). what kind of assembler you try to use? it depends on the assembler how to reserve 48 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the question and you need statically allocate space for some data structure with predefined size, you must replace line

```
      .align 48
```

by the next one

```
      times 48 db 0
```

This is true way  at least for the NASM. In any case I would recomend you to look at your assembler manual to ensure that this construct is supported by you assembly compiler. It is highly possible that your compiler can support not exactly the same notation as in the above example, but in any case it will support some similar analog. 'times' command have the next sintax:

```
    times <number of repeats> <body>
```

where  specifies how many times body will be inserted into the resulting code and  contain some standard assembly instruction. In the example above it is allocation of byte of the memory with initialization to null. So, for example, the next two code sections are equal

```
     times 5 dd 012345678h
```

and

```
     dd 012345678h
     dd 012345678h
     dd 012345678h
     dd 012345678h
     dd 012345678h
```

.align directive isn't correct for memory space allocation. It have another purpose - aligning of the following chunk of code or data to some predefined value. For example, in this case

```
    VAR1 db 0
    .align 48
    VAR2 db 0
```

if address of the VAR1 will be 0x1234, then the compiler will insert 44 unused bytes just to ensure that address of VAR2 will be alligned to the 48 bytes boundary. In our case it will be address - 0x1260 (0x1260 = 0x62 * 30 **+ 0**). If be honest, compilers usually allow aligning only to the value that is power of two, and it is highly possible that on compilation of the above example assembler will rise an error, because 48 isn't a power of two. So, it is hard to control how many unused bytes will be allocated by .align directive. It can be any value from 0 to directive parameter. And this value will change in reply to the changes in the source code of your program.

But NOTE! This is an approach for the statical memory allocation during compilation time! If you need dynamical memory allocation in the run time, you need to write your own or find and adopt some third party memory allocator. If you program will run in the OS environment, you can request dynamical memory allocation by using OS API. (for example VirtualAlloc in WinAPI).